# ClickOnce Application keeps Failing

Tags: clickonce, winscp, ftp-client

I'm trying to publish my ClickOnce application, It's showing success In the OutPut

```
Publish success.
http://cardknoxdemo.com/solutionsteam/publish.htm
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 2:06 PM and took 04:38.902 minutes ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish started at 2:06 PM and took 04:38.902 minutes ==========
```

but it's not opening the download URL by itself, so when I type it manually and trying to install it I get the below errors in my logs

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.19045.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.19041.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/mekstein/Downloads/solutions%20(8).application
    Deployment Provider url     : http://fps104/solutions/solutions.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\mekstein\Downloads\solutions (8).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://fps104/solutions/solutions.application did not succeed.
        + Unable to connect to the remote server
        + No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.50.146:80

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [8/1/2023 2:11:15 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\mekstein\Downloads\solutions (8).application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [8/1/2023 2:11:19 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://fps104/solutions/solutions.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Unable to connect to the remote server
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
        - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.50.146:80
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
            at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I'm using FTP server from Bluehost and WInSCP,  I put in for the Installation Folder URL "http://cardknoxdemo.com/solutionsteam/",

I tried resetting everything, not sure what else to do